# How to redirect STDOUT from all executables that output more than one screen of text to a pager?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How to stop *all* executables to dump long output to STDOUT?

In other words, I'd like to see the output which goes directly to a terminal to be truncated to the one screen of text or just altogether redirected to a `pager`. (in case of none of `|`, `>`, `<` is used).

For example, when I run `git log --help`, instead of dumping a help to STDOUT or STDERR, git opens a pager, which is `less`. When I quit a pager, the screen stays empty from a garbage, just a nice list of commands I have typed. I would like to have this behavior by default for any executable that dumps more than one screen of text to the terminal.

Note: I know how to use pipelining, the question is not about it.

Comment: Note sure what your intention is - most executables will write to STDOUT and STDERR, virtually no executables will write "directly to TTY" (whatever this is supposed to mean). You can't "stop" executables from writing to STDOUT. You can redirect STDOUT for executables to `/dev/null`, and you can write some wrapper to start executables in this way, but that's about it, and then in most cases you'll see no output **at all**. There is also no "automatic paging" builtin in the shells I use (possible some shells exists with this feature).

Comment: An example of what you want to achieve would be nice to have. Your question is not in line with your title. The title says "stop", but the question reads "no more than two screenfuls".

Comment: I do not know what you are asking for: ”Somehow it seems to fill my head with ideas--only I don't exactly know what they are! However, you don't like output or something: that's clear, at any rate

Comment: Do you want to process the output of a command (truncate too-long strings) then write to terminal?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify what I want.

Comment: This is, in effect, impossible without cooperation from the executable. What is Vim's (or nano's or lynx's) output? Or that of commands that do use pagers, like man? What about commands that output different things based on whether the output is to a TTY or to a pipe?

Comment: -----------------------

Comment: Vim or nano fit to a single screen so these will not be affected. If command uses a pager that can be easily detect, i.e. no need to engage if pager already running. It has to be done anyway, as it will be infinite loop of pagers. The last argument with TTY does not work at all as it is already solved as implementated.